# Doubt on proving a given application is symmetric.

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, solution-verification, applications

**Exercise.** Prove that a certain application, with $d(x,x) = 0$ is a pseudo-metric iff $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(z,y).$

**What I've done so far.** I have been able to prove the $(\Rightarrow)$ implication and almost proven the $(\Leftarrow)$ implication aswell. The only doubt I am having is how to prove that $d$ is a symmetric application, knowing only the last inequality is valid. What I've dont to try it is the followig:

For $y=x$ we have:
\begin{equation*}
d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(z,y) \Leftrightarrow d(x,z) \leq d(x,x) + d(z,x) \Leftrightarrow d(x,z) \leq d(z,x).
\end{equation*}
Now, to prove the symmetric I would also have to prove that $d(x,z) \geq d(x,z).$ This is where I am having trouble. I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly is the statement you are proving? The exercise says you must prove "the following application". What is this "following application"?

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. I have no information about the application besides $d(x,x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in X$. The exercises states that I should prove that if $d$ is a pseudo-metric (i.e. non-negative, symmetric, positive defined and the triangle inequality is valid) the inequality above is valid. I should also prove that if the above inequality is valid, then $d$ is a pseudo-metric (i.e. verifies all the properties i stated). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already proved (let's call this statement *1*) the following statement:

> For all values $x,z$, the inequality $$d(x,z)\leq d(z,x)$$ is true.

---

Now, take some value $x', z'$. Then,  define $x=z'$ and $z=x'$. Then, from what you already proved, you can see that

$$d(z',x')=d(x, z)\leq d(z,x)=d(x', z')$$

which means that you also have statement *2*, which says

> for all $x', z'$, the inequality $$d(z',x')\leq d(x',z')$$ is true.

---

Now, take any two values $x,z$.

From statement *1*, you know that $d(x,z)\leq d(z,x)$.

From statement *2*, you know that $d(z, x)\leq d(x,z)$.

Therefore, $d(x,z)=d(z,x)$.